# comparing the delta between two numbers from NSArray in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to find out the best way to compare adjacent numbers in an array and to make sure they are withing +/- 5 of the  current value.

I havent done any code as I dont know where to start however I will try to explain what I am trying to achive below.

```
// if you had an NSArray of numbers
objectAtIndex:0 = 200
//compaire that with 
object at Index:1 = 205
```

OR

```
objectAtIndex:4 = 300
//compaire that with 
object at Index:5 = 305
// and also compaire it with
object at Index:4 = 495
```

So what I need to do is comapire each index item with the values adjacent to the current index.

I have looked on [Foundation Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) however I am unable to find any sort of method I may be able to use to do this.

Comment: Have you tried writing code?

Comment: I am trying, I was confused at the begining thinking that i had to compaire both adjacent numbers in the array with the current number at the same time. however I should only need to just step through one by one and compaire with the next number.

Comment: Think how you'd do it if you had everything written on paper.  Do it that way.  There's no magic.

Comment: okay, thanks I just thought there may have been a method that dose it that I wasnt awear of. should i delete this question?

Comment: Even if there is a built-in function, you need to understand at least the basics of how you'd code it yourself in order to understand the built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try comparing like this below:-

```
NSArray *arr=@[@200,@300,@400,@500];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<arr.count; i++)
    {
        NSInteger j=i+1;
        if (j <=arr.count -1)
        {
           if ([arr[i] compare:arr[j]]==NSOrderedAscending)
           {
               NSLog(@"%ld",i);

           }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%ld",i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't compare two `NSNumber` objects with the `<` operator.